# How to get all the image sources on a particular Page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I am using a simple script to find an image on a page and get its source.

```
function img_find() {
    var img_find2 = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src;
    return img_find;
}
```

However when I go to write this function on my page it only finds the first image and then stops. What is the best way to have it print all of the image src's on the current page?
Thanks!

Comment: "it only finds the first image" - `document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]` mmm?

Comment: Yeah, It will fetch only one image src from a particular page even though there is multiple images on the page.

Comment: @Andrey was trying to put your attention on the `[0]` which you have there to get the 1st item of the array.

Comment: When you call `document.getElementsByTagName("img")` you get an array of elements containing SRCs of all IMG elements, and then you get the first element's SRC by using this `[0]`.

Comment: you question is like this: I take first image on page (`[0]`), however it only finds the first image.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You indeed told the code to do so. Don't do that. Just tell it to loop over all images and push the src of each in an array and return the array with all srcs instead.

```js
function img_find() {
    return Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("img")).map(i => i.src);
}
```

Or when you're not on ES6 yet

```js
function img_find() {
    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var imgSrcs = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        imgSrcs.push(imgs[i].src);
    }

    return imgSrcs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this BalusC but it didn't load any img src.

Comment: It should work fine if the document has images. Perhaps you're misinterpreting the return value? It returns an array. Or you're running it too early? Do it on `window.onload` or put the script at end of body, right before `</body>`.

Comment: Got it! One last thing: I use this to write the img urls on the page img_find = img_find();

document.write('test'+img_find); but it out puts the results like this http://www.domain.com/image.png,http://www.domain.com/image.png is there anyway to break them up? so maybe there is a break in between them.

Answer (score 2):

It may help you...

```
img=document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(i=0; i<img.length; i++) {
    imgp = imgp + img[i].src + '<br/>'; 
}
document.write(imgp);
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you formatted your code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I searched the whole web for a solution to this, maybe this will help if someone else searches the same.

```
for(var i = 0; i< document.images.length; i++){
document.images[i].style.border = "1px solid #E0FDA6";
}
```

Meaning, search all images that have style tag (border in this example) and set all borders to E0FDA6 (useful to reset single highlighted images), but I guess it can be used for everything with style tag.

Rg, Anjanka

Answer (score 0):

To print on current page (replace content):

```
document.write(`<pre>${JSON.stringify(Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementsByTagName("img"), img => img.src), null, 2)}</pre>`);
```

To save in array:

```
const imgs = Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementsByTagName("img"), img => img.src);
```

To just console dir/log directly:

```
console.dir(Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementsByTagName("img"), img => img.src));
console.log(Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementsByTagName("img"), img => img.src));
```

Answer (score -2):

Make it simple:

```
console.log(document.body.getElementsByTagName('img'));
```

Comment: it does not answer the question.