# Chrome Extensions : Get all images on page

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome-extension

After hours of reading in the Google-Documentations and Stackoverflow I decided to post this question. There already are some similar ones but I haven't found a answer that really helped me.
However, I'm trying to get a list of all images embeded on a page to use it in the Chrome extension. I've tried to do it with simle Javascript (document.images) but didn't get any entries. After some research I found out, that the only way to read elements from a page is using a EventListener. The function should be started using the chrome context-menu.

```
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "ExampleFunction", 
    contexts:["page"], 
    onclick: exampleFunction,
});
```

This part works fine, but how do I get the images after calling the function?
I've tried some ways using eventlisteners and finally got this function:

```
function downloadImages(info,tab) {
    alert('o');
    chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(result){
        for (var i in result.images) {
            allImages.push(result.images[i]);
        }
        alert(allImages[0]);
    });
}
```

The first alert works perfect but everything else is just doing nothing.

Comment: can't you just use: `Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("img")).map(i => i.src);` (I didn't make that, it was at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809051/how-to-get-all-the-image-sources-on-a-particular-page-using-javascript))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you have to actually get the images, and the way to do that is to use a [`content script`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html). I am assuming that your onclick was a typo and that you have this instead:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "ExampleFunction", 
  contexts:["page"], 
  onclick: downloadImages,
});
```

Then you would want to have something like this:

```
function downloadImages(info,tab) {
  alert('o');
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{file:"script.js"});
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message){
  //In case you want to do other things too this is a simple way to handle it
  if(message.method == "downloadImages"){
    message.images.forEach(function(v){
      allImages.push(v);
    });
    alert(allImages[0]);
  }
});
```

And then for your script.js:

```
var images = [];
for(var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++){
  images.push(document.images[i].src);
}
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method:"downloadImages",images:images});
```

This grabs the array of images and sends back the `src` of each image to your background page so you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems like there is a problem recieving the data from the content script. I've added some more alerts to the code to see where it fails. The script sends a message to the background.js but the code within the function is not processed. The console gives me this error:   
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON event_bindings:66
chromeHidden.JSON.stringify event_bindings:66
PortImpl.postMessage miscellaneous_bindings:58
chromeHidden.Port.sendMessageImpl miscellaneous_bindings:262
(anonymous function) runtime:45
(anonymous function) [...]

Comment: @cbo ahh, that is my bad, when I looked at it I thought it was an array. You'll have to put into a more manageable form before you send it through a message. Do you just want the `src` for the images?

Comment: Yep, the purpose of this extension is to get the image behind a thumbnail by playing with the thumbnails source. I thougt this would be nice way to learn some more about managing strings and patterns in javascript (beside that I haven't seen such an extension yet)

Comment: @cbo, I updated my answer to get rid of the JSON error. Try doing it like that.

Comment: Thanks, it worked this way :)
In the first try it just returned one url as "v" and crashed at "allImages.push(v);". Solved this by initializing "allImages" first via "var allImages = new Array();"